# How to get back modified file after git checkout and git pull?

Tags: git, pull, git-checkout, revert

I've modified a file, then I want to get latest version from remote.

So I run git checkout to revert the file, and run git pull to get latest version.

After that, I found that I need the modification of the file.

Is it possible to get it back? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `"git stash"` to stash all of your changes, `"git pull"` to update your repository, and then `"git stash apply"` to apply your changes back.

Answer (score 1):

If you have done the git checkout -- file to revert than it's too late...simply the changes are lost...A better idea might have been to stash the change instead of reverting it...